# Python Typing: Type hint parameter with the type of the object that the function is in

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Hard to explain in title but the question is simple.
How can I make this run.

```
class A:
    def foo(self, param: A) -> A:
        pass
```

Comment: It does run, in Python 3.10 or newer - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/. If you mean how can you make it pass type checking, then given that foo should return an instance of A but returns None it's tricky to square that circle.

Comment: You can use `'A'` instead.

Comment: See linked dupe. `from __future__ import annotations` will sort you until 3.10+, where it just works.